# Derivation of function$~g(x)=f(x)+f(-x)~$is an even function where$~f(x)~$is an arbitrary continuous function.

Tags: functions, continuity, even-and-odd-functions

> Let$~f~$be any function which is defined for all numbers. Show that$~g(x)=f(x)+f(-x)~$is even.

$$\operatorname{e.g.}~f(x)=x^2\implies g(x)=x^2+(-x)^2=2x^2\leftarrow~~\text{even}\tag{1}$$

$$\operatorname{e.g.}~f(x)=x^3\implies g(x)=x^3+(-x)^3=0\leftarrow~~\text{even}\tag{2}$$

$$\operatorname{e.g.}~f(x)=x^3+x^2~~\leftarrow~~\text{neither even nor odd}\tag{3}$$

$$\implies~g(x)=(x^3+x^2)+(-x^3+x^2)=2x^2\leftarrow\text{even}\tag{4}$$

But how it can be proven that the claim holds?

And needless to say, can I completely assume "for all numbers" in the problem statements belong to a set of complex numbers(handling imaginary numbers is also required in this problem)?

Comment: Hint: by definition $g(x)$ is even if $g(x) = g(-x)$ holds for all $x$. Try to show this for your function $g(x) = f(x) + f(-x)$.

Comment: Yeah the domain of $f$ doesn’t actually matter here. We would only require that addition commutes in the codomain (this is definitely beside the point here). You have $$g(x) = f(x) + f(-x) = g(-x)$$ which is the definition of an even function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think you define the concept of "even" or "odd" functions for functions of a complex variable. I will assume it is real. You have
$$
g(-x)=f(-x)+f(-(-x))=f(-x)+f(x)=g(x)
$$
so $g$ is even.

Comment: No you could definitely have an even function defined on the complex plane (and take on complex values)

Comment: Sure. Those functions would have a symmetry w.r.t. $0$. My point is that  I have never seen the terminology "even" or "odd" used here.